# More Efficient Way to Destructure with Conditional in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, destructuring

I have this code in which we retrieve the data or get the data using `useQuery`. However, it fails anytime I attempt to call it using this method.

```
const { data: {getSubCategories} } = useQuery(FETCH_SUBCATEGORIES_QUERY);
```

It appears to throw an error stating that 'getSubCategories' is undefined, so I tried this method:

```
const { getSubCategories: subCategories } = { ...subCategoryData };
const { getChildCategory } = { ...data };
```

It works, but I think there is a better approach or more efficient way to destructure something with conditional syntaxes so it can't return undefined I guess I seem to notice it will take a few seconds before it will return data.

Would you mind commenting down below if you don't understand what I am trying to say or need more clarifications. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It appears to throw an error stating that 'getSubCategories' is undefined

No, it's throwing an error when `data` is `undefined`. You can circumvent that by using a default:

```
const { data: {getSubCategories} = {} } = useQuery(FETCH_SUBCATEGORIES_QUERY);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you can try this: (safely destruct from the object)

```
const { data: {getSubCategories} } = useQuery(FETCH_SUBCATEGORIES_QUERY) || {};
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, but it returns undefined reading of getSubCategories